# PHP preg_replace with variable value using found expression as key

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have a string `$src` with two variable placeholders `%%itemA%%` and `%%itemB%%`. The idea is for the regular expression to match any term listed `ITEMA|ITEMB|ITEMC`, case insensitively, and replace the term with the value of the array item using the term as the array key.

```
$replacements = [
    'itemA' => 'replacedItemA',
    'itemB' => 'replacedItemB',
    'itemC' => 'replacedItemC'
];

$src = "A B C %%itemA%% D E F %%itemB%% G H I";

$src = preg_replace('/\%\%(ITEMA|ITEMB|ITEMC)%%/i', $replacements['\1'], $src);

echo $src;
```

In this example the expected result is for `%%itemA%%` to be replaced with `$replacements['itemA']`'s value and `%%itemB%%` to be replaced with `$replacements['itemB']`'s value

Expected output from the `echo` was

> A B C replacedItemA D E F replacedItemB G H I

Actual output, oddly, simply replaced the found terms with nothing (note the double spaces where the variable was removed)

> `A B C  D E F  G H I`

Why is the term's string not being used in the `$replacements['key']` to use the value of the array variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. Since you are dealing with literal strings, you can avoid the regex and use a faster way:

```
$replacements = [
    '%%itemA%%' => 'replacedItemA',
    '%%itemB%%' => 'replacedItemB',
    '%%itemC%%' => 'replacedItemC'
];

$str = strtr($str, $replacements);
```

Comment: Hi, my understanding is that the regex is more efficient, as there will be a lot of strings filtered through? I'll do some benchmarking to test if I can find a solution to make my approach work too

Comment: @CraigMcArthur: "my understanding is that the regex is more efficient": it's a totally false idea!

Comment: Unless there is a need to also modify the `$replacements`, and specify some additional context for `%%...%%` strings, this can be used, too. Regex allows some more things that mere `strtr` does not.

Comment: The `$replacements` should be also modified to include delimiters to use this approach. If it is not possible, it not usable.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the `preg_replace` with `preg_replace_callback` like this:

```
$src = preg_replace_callback('/%%(ITEM[ABC])%%/i', function ($m) use ($replacements) {
 return isset($replacements[$m[1]]) ? $replacements[$m[1]] : $m[0];
}
, $src);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/n8yBQv)

The issue is that `\1` backreference can only be used inside the pattern to refer to the text captured with the first capturing group or inside a replacement pattern, but only as a literal part of it. The `\1` is not automatically evaluated to be used as an argument.

I also contracted the pattern a bit, but I guess it is just a sample.